# Search a CheckedListBox that is bounded to a datatable using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a CheckedListBox (winforms) with data that is bounded to a datatable:

```
clbCustomer.DataSource = ds.Tables["Default"];
clbCustomer.DisplayMember = "desc";
clbCustomer.ValueMember = "customerId";
```

Now I would like to search the checkedlistbox for a particular customer id and then select that row.  I can do this with a foreach statement as follows:

```
// Find the index
int index = 0;
foreach (DataRowView item in clbCustomer.Items)
{
    int cusId = Convert.ToInt32(item["customerId"]);
    if (cusId == 255)
    {
        break;
    }
    index++;
}
// Select the customer
clbCustomer.SetItemChecked(index, true);
```

However, it seems very bulky to do it this way.  I am attempting to convert the above code into linq but have not been able to accomplish it.  Here is what I have so far:

```
// Find the index (not working)
int index = clbCustomer.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(x => x["customerId"] == 255);
// Select the customer
clbCustomer.SetItemChecked(index, true);
```

But not sure how to extract the index of that customer id using linq.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

**Solution provided by Keithin8a below:**

```
var item = clbCustomer.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["customerId"]) == 255).FirstOrDefault();

int index = clbCustomer.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

Comment: Does this line -  int index = clbCustomer.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(x => x["customerId"] == 255);  can be compiled at all? Seems here returned result is a collection. So maybe you can fix it with add FirstorDefault? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  No, that line does not work at all.  That is what I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: var index = clbCustomer.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(x => x["customerId"] == 255).FirstOrDefaut();clbCustomer.SetItemChecked(index.customerId, true); Probably may help =)

Comment: @РоманИванов customer Id might not be the same as its index in the collection or else you would be able to just use `index == 255`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq statements like that return a collection as mentioned in the comments. If you were to use

```
var item = clbCustomer.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["customerId"]) == 255).FirstOrDefault()
```

That would get you your a single item instead of a collection. You can then get the index of this item by calling

```
int index = clbCustomer.Items.IndexOf(item);
```

That should get you what you want.

Comment: Looks like answer =) I missed some requirements in my answer you found them =)

Comment: Keith good job that was it!  Just one tweak if you want to update your answer: var item = clbCustomer.Items.Cast<DataRowView>().Where(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["customerId"]) == 255).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @RobertSmith update my answer now, glad you found it useful :)

Comment: @РоманИванов I've made the same mistake many times in the past so I was quick to spot it, but it was tricky. Making mistakes is the best way to learn in this industry.